# Symfony2 validator, NotBlank but allow null

Tags: php, symfony, validation, silex

I'm having trouble validating a value to allow NULL but not an empty string with the Symfony2 validator component.

I've integrated the component in a Silex application and used the Property Constraint target to validate some properties of my Application Entities (not a Doctrine Entity).

I've added this static method to my Entity class to validate name and service_id on my Entity, problem is that when `service_id` is NULL which should be valid the `NotBlank` constraint kicks in and reports a violation.

```
static public function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
    // name should never be NULL or a blank string
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('name', new Assert\NotNull());
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('name', new Assert\NotBlank());

    // service_id should either be a non-blank string or NULL
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('service_id', new Assert\NotBlank());
}
```

Bottomline, I'm looking how to allow either a String or NULL as `service_id` but not allow an empty string.

PS: I've also tried the `MinLength(1)` constraint but that allows empty strings unfortunately.

Comment: There is a Null-Validator, but it won't help you either, as only NULL will be valid, i.e. if it's a string (empty or not) it will be violated. Why not write a custom Validator?

Comment: A custom validator is indeed an option but to me it seemed such a common usecase that it's hard to believe it's impossible to do out of the box.

Comment: Me, too. In fact this seems even wrong (or at least the wording). For me NotBlank means that there should be a validation for a blank string. I don't understand why the constraint treats null as a blank value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `NotBlank` constraint treats `null` as a blank value, as can be seen [in this test](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Tests/Constraints/NotBlankValidatorTest.php#L57).

When using doctrine, this can be solved by using the [Valid](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) constraint. If the value of the field is not `null`, it will attempt to validate it.

Since you are not using doctrine entities, you'll probably have to use a callback validator or write your own constraint.

## EDIT

To answer your new question on adding a callback constraint as a property constraint: No, it is not possible to do that.

The callback constraint acts on the whole object, not just a single property. Here's an example of how you can use the callback constraint:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider());

class Person
{
    public $name;

    public function validateName(ExecutionContext $context)
    {
        if ('John Doe' === $this->name) {
            $context->addViolationAtPath('name', 'Name must not be "John Doe"');
        }
    }

    static public function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addConstraint(new Assert\Callback(array('validateName')));
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('name', new Assert\NotNull());
    }
}

$person = new Person();
$person->name = 'John Doe';
$violations = $app['validator']->validate($person);
var_dump('Violations for John Doe');
var_dump((string) $violations);

$person = new Person();
$violations = $app['validator']->validate($person);
var_dump('Violations for Person with name null');
var_dump((string) $violations);

$person = new Person();
$person->name = 'Igor Wiedler';
$violations = $app['validator']->validate($person);
var_dump('Violations for Igor Wiedler');
var_dump((string) $violations);
```

Comment: From what I've tried callback validators won't work on property constraints in Silex or am I wrong?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how to use the callback constraint.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone who runs into this on a later version (4.3 onwards), you can set `allowNull = true`:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class SomeEntity
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(allowNull = true)
     */
    protected $someProperty;
}
```